# Connect to remote port(Server) from thread in polling

Tags: java, sockets, exception, thread-safety, serversocket

I want to connect to a remote server from thread and keep sending strings. If the connection gets refused the thread should keep polling the port until the server is up again. How can I handle this exception and keep my thread fro crashing? The server may not be up for long time but thread should run indefinitely.

```
public void SendMessage(String message){
    try {
        socket = new Socket(actuatorAddress, destPort.get());
        outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
        out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        out.flush();
        out.write(message.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I changed some part of the code as below. For first time called Connect function and then subsequently called Send Message function through thread. The delay added to reconnecting helped reduce time lag recurred due to connecting to non existing server. Still think that there might be a better solution to the basic problem.

```
public boolean ConnectToActuator() {
    try {
        if(actuatorAddress.isReachable(2000)){
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.setPerformancePreferences(1, 2, 0);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(false);
            socket.setSendBufferSize(32);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(actuatorAddress, destPort.get()));
            outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
            out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
            connected = true;
            disconnectedTimeout = 0;
        }
    }catch (ConnectException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        connected = false;
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return connected;
}

public boolean SendToActuator(String message) {
    if(connected == false){ //socket.isOutputShutdown()
        disconnectedTimeout++;
        if(disconnectedTimeout>20){
            disconnectedTimeout = 0;
            ConnectToActuator();
        } else {
            return connected;
        }
    }
    try {
        out.flush();
        out.writeBytes(message);
        disconnectedTimeout = 0;
        connected = true;
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        connected = false;
        System.out.println(uhe.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        connected = false;
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'long time' in terms of minutes?  Also, what is the goal of your code: are you trying to test if the service is up, or make 100% sure that the message will eventually be sent even if you have no idea when the service will become available?  Do you care if some messages get lost as long as some of them get through occasionally?  Or do you need to be sure they are all received?

Comment: The goal is that there are around 10 servers connected in the network reading messages from this thread. There can be disconnection of server for several minutes or even Hours or it might be taken out of the network. But still I want the Task to keep running and sending messages to other servers who are connected. The loss of messages is not a problem.

Comment: Basically I want to handle Connection refused Exception. Or better if I can check if connection is going to be refused before creating a socket.

Comment: So the idea is to try to connect to all of the servers and if none are up you can discard the message?

Comment: Yes. I added catch "ConnectException" for handling this exception but it is causing time lag in sending messages to connected servers.

Comment: You might need an infinite loop where you try to connect but also, where you catch the connection exception and try again to reconnect. This is not efficient, and let me tell you that there is a better solution like `websockets`, which auto-manage the threads and polling for you. It's a hot JDK7+ feature worth to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following constraints in the comments:

- Try to send the message to one of the 10 servers.
- If none of the servers are available to receive the message, discard the message.

What you actually want to do is:

1. Iterate through a list of server addresses
2. Attempt to send a message to each of them
3. Break out of the loop right away if successful
4. Catch any errors on connection failure and try the next server

Here's an example class that will run through that scenario.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessageSender {
  private static final Integer destPort = 1234;

  private static final String[] serverAddresses = {
    "address1",
    "address2",
    "address3" // Etc....
  };

  public Boolean SendMessage(String message) {
    Boolean messageSentSuccessfully = false;
    for (String addy : serverAddresses) {
      messageSentSuccessfully = SendMessageToServer(addy, message);
      if (messageSentSuccessfully) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return messageSentSuccessfully;
  }

  private Boolean SendMessageToServer(String serverAddress, String message) {
    Boolean messageSent = false;
    try {
      Socket dataSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, destPort);
      OutputStream outToServer = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
      DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
      out.write(message.getBytes());
      out.flush();
      messageSent = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    return messageSent;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you TreyE. I tried to check if the remote server is available by using InetSocketAddress(actuatorAddress, destPort.get()).getAddress().isReachable(timeout) but this only checks if the remote IP is reachable and not the if the specific port is reachable.

Comment: The thing is, you don't really care if the server is available or not, you just care if you can send the message.  So you might as well try to send the message.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo:

```
while(true){
  if(connect()) DoClientConnectedStuff();
  sleep(reconnectTimeout);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

please try below changes. if your connection refuses it will wait for 2s(2000ms) and then again try to connect with server. if connection being successful it will take outputstream, write data in a while loop and flush the data.

```
public void createSocketConnection() throws IOException
{     
    socket = new Socket(actuatorAddress, destPort.get());
    if(socket!=null)
        {
          outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
          out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
        }

}

public void SendMessage(String message){
    boolean isRunning=false;
    try 
    {
        createSocketConnection();
        isRunning=true;
        while(isRunning)
        {
          out.write(message.getBytes());
          out.flush();
       }
    } catch (java.net.ConnectException conExcp) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        try{
          Thread.sleep(2000);
        }catch(Exception ee){}
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    } 
}
```

Comment: 'socket' cannot possibly be null at the pint you're testing it. You're not costing the socket. This code does not retry anything. -1